# Loop over lists in Xpath

Tags: python, xpath

How would I loop over a list in the Xpath? I thought it was similar to using the `.format` function like it would when looping over a string, this obviously does not work. I wanted to get the `href` from each list - for example:

```
for i in range(0, 15):
    test_page = response.xpath('.//li[{i}]/a[@class="pagination__item"]/@href').format(i)
```

Taken from the link: https://www.ebay.com/b/Collectible-Card-Games-Accessories/2536/bn_1852210?LH_BIN=1&LH_PrefLoc=2&mag=1&rt=nc&_pgn=4&_sop=16

Expected output:
A way to index `i` or some type of boolean logic i.e. to select between 1 and 30.

Comment: The `{i}` would require you use an `f` string which would look like this `response.xpath(f'.//li[{i}]/a[@class="pagination__item"]/@href')`. Just add `f` before the string and do not include `.format(i)`

Comment: You can also replace `{i}` with `{}` if you want to use `format()`.

Comment: @Guy and you can simply post it as an answer and get points :)